# .NET MAUI Binding Converter

Tags: data-binding, maui, .net-maui

I try to use the `Frame` `WidthRequest` property as an `ConverterParameter` for my `rssiToLayoutBounds` converter like this:

```xml
<Frame
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding Rssi, Converter={StaticResource rssiToLayoutBounds}, ConverterParameter={Binding Source={RelativeSource Self}, Path=WidthRequest}}"
    WidthRequest="5">
```

But in my converter i receive `{Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Binding}` instead of an integer.

```cs
public class RssiToLayoutBounds : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // parameter is type of Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Binding but i would like an integer value
```

How can i do this ?

## Some details

The goal is that
[*Same as progress bar*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35Iph.jpg)

I have the Rssi Bluetooth value which is between -25 and -100. I map this value in percent; -25 = 100% and -100 = 0%.

```cs
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    int Rssi = (int)value;
    int Percent = Tools.Lerp(-100, -25, 0, 100, Rssi);
    return new Rect((int)(Percent - (int)parameter / 2.0), 0, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize);
}
```

I would like to move the round according to the percent value.

In "background" it's a `Frame` with `LinearGradientBrush`. For simplicity, the `WidthRequest` of this `Frame` is 100.

The round is also a `Frame`. The `WithRequest` of this frame is variable.

I would like to have the round centered on the percent value. With a `AbsoluteLayout` i must do

```cs
AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds value = new Rect((int)(Percent - (int)parameter / 2.0), 0, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize, AbsoluteLayout.AutoSize);
```

For this, i must have the parameter which is filled with the `WidthRequest` of the *front* `Frame`.

```xml
<AbsoluteLayout>
    <Frame
        CornerRadius="20"
        HeightRequest="8"
        WidthRequest="100">
        <Frame.Background>
            <!-- StartPoint defaults to (0,0) -->
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#ff0000"
                Offset="0.1" />
                <GradientStop Color="#ffff00"
                Offset="0.5" />
                <GradientStop Color="#00ff00"
                Offset="1.0" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Frame.Background>
    </Frame>
    <Frame
        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="{Binding Rssi, Converter={StaticResource rssiToLayoutBounds}, ConverterParameter='5'}"
        CornerRadius="10"
        BackgroundColor="#30000000"
        HeightRequest="8"
        WidthRequest="5">
    </Frame>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

I could use a slider or a progress bar such as AlohaKit but I'm learning and I would like to be able to do it myself with Binding and Converters

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in [this issue](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/8099) for Xamarin.Forms, the `ConverterParameter` does not support data binding.

The suggested way is to use [MultiBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/multibinding). With a `MultiBinding` you can evaluate multiple properties of your data bound object and convert that back to the object you're expecting.

I'd love to give you a more tailored answer to your situation, but unfortunately there isn't enough code to know what you're trying to do.