# How to pass value from xamarin page to ivalueconverter class properties Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a class of IValueConverter with a property named myValue which I want to divide the ivalueconverter by its property myValue! But, I want to know if it is possible to pass the myValue from xamarin page to ivalueconverter? If yes, how?

**IvalueConverter**

```
class salesUIbtnWidth : IValueConverter
{
    public double myValue { get; set; }
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (double)value / myValue;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Try Implementing the class**

```
 <Button Text="Click me" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center"
         CornerRadius="15" WidthRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference 
         frame}, Path=Width,Converter={StaticResource salesUIbtnWidth}}">
 </Button>//how to bind also the MyValue
```

All I want is to know how to set **myValue** in page and pass it to **(IvalueConverter)** from xamarin during runtime!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72601728/net-maui-bonding-converter

Comment: Thanks @Jason, but the question was not answered from the link too!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your question this is what you need to do!

Following @Jessie Zhang example

```
<Button HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   HeightRequest="{Binding Source={x:Reference frame}, Path=Height,
                   Converter={StaticResource doubleToInt}, ConverterParameter=enterYOURvaluHERE}"></Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the value by `ConverterParameter`.

You can refer to the sample code:

```
<Label Text="{Binding Red,
                  Converter={StaticResource doubleToInt},
                  ConverterParameter=255,
                  StringFormat='Red = {0:X2}'}" />


 <local:DoubleToIntConverter x:Key="doubleToInt" />
```

**DoubleToIntConverter.cs**

```
public class DoubleToIntConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)Math.Round((double)value * GetParameter(parameter));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value / GetParameter(parameter);
    }

    double GetParameter(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter is double)
            return (double)parameter;

        else if (parameter is int)
            return (int)parameter;

        else if (parameter is string)
            return double.Parse((string)parameter);

        return 1;
    }
}
```

For more, you can check: [Binding Converter Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/converters#binding-converter-parameters)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use parameter, you can define MyValue when you create the converter.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <app1:MyConverter x:Key="myConverter" MyValue="255"/>
</ContentPage.Resources>
```